# When to use i.e. and e.g?

Tags: abbreviations

I have seen a lot in common use of the abbreviations i.e. and e.g. but I'm not pretty sure when and how to use these abbreviations.

Answer (score 1):

They are shorts for "id est" and "exempli gratia" (latin terms for "that is" and "for example"). I use "i.e." to clarify the meaning of a term, and "e.g" to give an example of a term, and I usually put the between (). Examples:

All english speaking countries (e.g. Australia) are passing new laws prohibiting the learning of french.

A European person (i.e. a person who is born in a European country) is likely to spend most of his life in Europe.

Comment: Your `i.d.` should be `i.e.` And `An european` should be `A European`.

Comment: Both of them...

Comment: I was asking myself "but I did fix both of those i.d...." :)

Comment: Good answer. It'd be a much _better_ answer for this site if it was sourced. Take a look at [how to answer](//www.stackexchange.org/help/how-to-answer) to learn a bit more about EL&U.